# How to use connection file of mongo db in other files of node.js application

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a file, *connection.js* that I want to use in another file. How can I use this file in another file for inserting and updating a database. 
For example I have another file named *item.js* in which I want to add the item details into the database.

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');

module.exports = function() {

    this.getConnection = function(callback) {

        var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
        var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ShoppingCart';

        console.log(url);

        MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
                return;
            } else {
                console.log('Connection established to', url);
                return callback;
            } //else

        }); //MongoClient.connect

    }; //Connection

}; //constructor
```

**item.js**

In this file the `addItem` function takes a JSON object which I want to store in the database. For that I need to connect to the database and then insert the result, but I don't understand how to connect to the database.

I tried this but it's not working:

```
 /**
  * Shopping Cart
  * @author Sunil Hirole
  * @Date 15-july-2015
  * This is an e-commerce application for purchasing items
  */

var prompt = require('prompt');
var item = require('../models/itemArray.js');
var Connection = require('../util/con.js');

/** 
  * Item class is a model class
  * It contains addItem,editItem,showItem,deleteItem functions 
 */

function Item(){
    this.id;
    this.name;
    this.price;
}//Item 

/**
  *addItem Function 
  **/

Item.prototype.addItem = function(result){
var connection = new Connection();
var db = connection.getConnection(function(err,db){});
var Collection = db.collection('ItemsArray');
Collection.insert([result], function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
        } 
    else {
        return result;
        }
//Close connection
db.close();
 });
  return(result);
  }//addItem
```

Comment: I think you are supposed to just open you database connection as soon as your application is initialised and then leave it open until your app stops. You shouldn't normally have to keep manually re-opening the connection in every file that uses Mongo. Also, have you tried using Mongoose? Using the native MongoDB drive looks quite painful.

Answer (score 4):

hello just try exporting the callback function in your line you have

```
module.exports = function(callback) {

    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/ShoppingCart';
    MongoClient.connect(url, callback)
```

instead of `function(err, db)` use the callback `MongoClient.connect(url, callback);`

latter in your **item.js** just use the connection var

```
var connection = require('../util/con.js');

// the rest of the file here

connection(function(err,db){
    db.collection('ItemsArray').
    insert([result], function(err, result) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
       return;
     } 
     else {
        return result;
     }
//Close connection
});
```